# How do I import a CSV file containing IP addresses into QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I am importing a CSV file into QuestDB and the IP addresses are being picked up as floats:

```sh
curl -F data=@ip.csv http://localhost:9000/imp
```

There are more columns, but you an IP like `1.2.3.4` comes out as `123.4`

| timestamp | ip |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z | 123.4 |
| 2020-01-01T01:36:00.000000Z | 1921680.1 |
| 2020-01-01T01:51:00.000000Z | 123.4 |

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to format the IP addresses explicitly as strings in your source CSV:

```
timestamp,Ip
2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z,"1.2.3.4"
2020-01-01T01:36:00.000000Z,"192.168.0.1"
```